# Does script include order in index.html matter for angularjs application?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

With my Angularjs application, the order doesn't seem to matter in the sense that there aren't any errors generated.   But when I setup my jasmine/karma tests within a grunt configuration file, I notice that I get a lot of module errors because the order was not setup properly.  I used the same order that I put in my index.html.

To the question, does the matter of my inputs in my index.html matter for an angularjs app, right now there are no errors but it still may be an issue down the road.

For example,

Lets say I have a file:

module1.js

```
var registrationApp = angular.module('registration', ['ui.router']);
    registrationApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'STATES', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, STATES) {   }
```

In this case, the module registration is being created above.

And then I may have another file:

module2.js:

```
  angular.module('registration').service('ActivityLogService', ActivityLogService);
```

Is it OK to do this?

```
<script src="module2.js">
<script src="module1.js">
```

If I do this in karma test, I need to have the proper order,

```
files: [
    'module1.js',
    'module2.js' ]
```

Comment: angular.module('plunker');
    angular.module('plunker', []); generates error in plunk in same js file.

Comment: For mine, it isn't the same file, do you have a index.html document and the script include example.   Either way, the order doesn't always matter when I do it the script include way.  At least, I don't get an error.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nnc3bTAkItt23BDAQMHR?p=preview also error